# how to use different "viewResolver" according to different "context:component-scan"

Tags: java, spring, jsp

If I scan the package1 with
 `<context:component-scan base-package="package1" />`
I have to use the views (jsp pages) under the folder    `/WEB-INF/pages`

If I scan the package2 with
 `<context:component-scan base-package="package2" />`
I have to use the views (jsp pages) under the folder    `/WEB-INF/pages2`

So, I'm wondering how I can order to my `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` class to use a

`<property name="prefix">` when scanning one package and use another  `<property name="prefix">` when scanning another package.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055610/creating-multiple-internalresourceviewresolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use two view resolvers

Say urlbasedviewresolver and Internalviewresolver and give a priority order to it.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages1/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages2</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```